# How to Draw Rounded Rectangle in API Level below 21 on a Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics, android-paint

I am creating a custom view by extending `android.view.View`.

Now, I need to draw a rounded rectangle on API level below 21. Android has a built in method name,`drawRoundRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float rx, float ry, Paint paint)` in `android.graphics.Canvas`, but It doesn't support API below 21, but **I need to draw this on API 16**. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Canvas#drawRoundRect` was introduced in API level 1, read the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) for more info

Comment: thanks for fast feedback.
I edited my ques, `drawRect(Rect r, Paint paint)` is available in API 1 but `drawRoundRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float rx, float ry, Paint paint)` in added in API 21

Comment: did you see the link i posted? did you try to press `^F` followed by `drawRoundRect`?

Comment: yes, i got it, thanks for reply

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got my solution after all!

Although [`drawRoundRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float rx, float ry, Paint paint)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRoundRect(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) is added in API level 21, there is another method, [`drawRect (RectF rect,Paint paint)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRoundRect(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) which is added in API level 1 that can be used instead.

Thanks [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) for the guide.

Example:

```
Rectf rectf= new Rectf(left, top, right, bottom);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectf,rx,ry, mPaint);
```